# Does Enum support hyphens?

Tags: apex, compile-error, enum

I am trying to create an enum datatype for relationships in my apex class. Below is the code I am using:

```
public Enum Enum_RelationShipCode {Father, Mother, Brother, Sister, Uncle, Aunt, Brother-In-Law, Daughter-In-Law, Child}
```

However, I am getting compile errors when trying to save the class as below.

```
Expecting '}' but was: '-'
Unexpected Token ','.
Unexpected Token '}'
```

Can someone help? It appears that Salesforce enums are not supporting hyphens in them.

Answer (score 5):

If you want any sort of word separation, you would need to use underscores instead, which are allowed.

```
public Enum RelationshipCode { BROTHER_IN_LAW }
```

Answer (score 5):

The `-` character, outside of a string, can only be used as a minus sign (negation or subtraction, depending on what's to the left of it), or as the decrement operator (`--`). It cannot be used as part of a "token", such as a field name, class name, variable name, enum, constant, function name, etc.